# Javascript create and delete iframes onClick

Tags: javascript

I tried reading informations but found myself lost.

Is there a way to create and delete an iframe using javascript?

To do: On button click create and delete an iframe 10 times, but I don't understand how I can close an iframe.

Js fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/fp87vb9j/1/

```
<html>
<body>
<button type="button" onclick="removeIFrame()">Click Me!</button>
  <div class="top" onclick="removeIFrame();"></div>
  <iframe id="iframe" src="www.google.com" width="200" height="100"></iframe>
  <div class="top"></div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function removeIFrame() {
var iframes = document.querySelectorAll('iframe');
for (var i = 0; i < iframes.length; i++) {
    iframes[i].parentNode.removeChild(iframes[i]);
}
}
</script>
</html>
```

I saw it now I forgot the  at the end, now it's working. is there a way also to recreate the iframes?

Edit 2: https://jsfiddle.net/fp87vb9j/2/

```
<html>
<body>
<button type="button" onclick="removeIFrame()">Click Me!</button>
  <div class="top" onclick="removeIFrame();"></div>
  <iframe id="iframe" src="www.google.com" width="200" height="100"></iframe>
  <div class="top"></div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function removeIFrame() {
var iframes = document.querySelectorAll('iframe');
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
var ifrm[i] = document.createElement("iframe");
        ifrm[i].setAttribute("src", "http://google.com/");
        ifrm[i].style.width = "640px";
        ifrm[i].style.height = "480px";
        document.body.appendChild(ifrm[i]);
        setInterval(div_show, 5 * 1000);
    iframes[i].parentNode.removeChild(iframes[i]);
}
}
</script>
</html>
```

New issue: Uncaught ReferenceError: createIFrames is not defined

```
<html>
<body>
<button type="button" onclick="removeIFrame()">Click Me!</button>
<button type="button" onclick="createIFrames()">Create iframe!</button>
  <div class="top" onclick="removeIFrame();"></div>

  <iframe id="iframe" src="www.google.com" width="200" height="100"></iframe>
  <div class="top"></div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function removeIFrame() {
var iframes = document.querySelectorAll('iframe');
for (var i = 0; i < iframes.length; i++) {
    iframes[i].parentNode.removeChild(iframes[i]);
}
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function createIFrames() {
var ifrm = document.createElement("iframe");
        ifrm.setAttribute("src", "http://hello.com/");
        ifrm.style.width = "640px";
        ifrm.style.height = "480px";
        document.body.appendChild(ifrm);

}
}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: share your code with us. best is to create a fiddle

Comment: added code + jsfiddle, thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 1):

You may try for this:

First create and iframe in HTML and then make an delete button and on action of delete button, this will work for deleting the iframe from your webpage

```
var iframes = document.querySelectorAll('iframe');
for (var i = 0; i < iframes.length; i++) {
    iframes[i].parentNode.removeChild(iframes[i]);
}
```

Comment: @ use the document.create elemetnt('iframe') within looping, and set the all attribute for this.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps. You can find the comments in the code below. Basically, need to wait until all iframes are loaded using `onload` event, then remove each iframe one by one.

```js
window.onload = function () {
 var count = 0; //set counter to 0

 //Create iframes
 for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
  var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
  iframe.src = "https://www.google.com";
    
  iframe.onload = function () {  //Check for onload event of iframe
    count++;  //Increment counter
    removeAllIframes(); //Call removeAllIFrames function
  };
    
  document.body.appendChild(iframe); //Append iframe to body element
 }

 function removeAllIframes() {
  if (count == 10) { //Execute removal of iframe only after all iframes have been loaded
    
   var iframes = document.querySelectorAll("iframe"); //Get all iframes
      
   for (var i = 0; i < iframes.length; i++) { //Loop through the iframes
    //Remove iframes one by one
    setTimeout(function(i) { return function() {iframes[i].parentNode.removeChild(iframes[i]) }; }(i), 1000*i);
   }
  }
 }
}
```